# When we execute docker run ubuntu:14.04 ps ax, where does ps ax command runs?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and have been reading the docs and i understand the concept of userspace and kernel space. so when we run the above command i.e. docker run ubutnu:14.04, it download a ubutnu image(which does not have kernel) and runs it inside the container and then fires the command ps ax. my question is where the ps ax command executes? does it execute on the host OS(which is a linux kernel as docker runs on linux) or does it execute inside the container and shows all the processes running in the ubuntu user-space ?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `ps` command should answer that question quite clearly.  Here is `ps ax` running on my host:

```
$ ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:10 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 23
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:08 [ksoftirqd/0]
    7 ?        S      2:20 [rcu_sched]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
    9 ?        S      1:31 [rcuos/0]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/0]
   [...many lines later...]
   20565 pts/3    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

And here it is running with `docker run`:

```
$ docker run ubuntu ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Rs+    0:00 ps ax
```

When you run `docker run ubuntu:14.04 ps ax`, your are running the `ps` command *inside the container*, and `ps` will only be able to see other processes running inside the same container.